# howto implement Synchronizer Token Pattern in classic asp

Tags: asp-classic

to prevent CSRF I want to implement the Synchronizer Token Pattern in my classic asp application.

I understand that iIshould generate a token in session_onstart. What I do not get is how to generate such a token as it should be random and unique. So a simple Rnd() and randomize will not work, right?

Furthermore should it be hashed in any way? How?

Thanks for any hints...

[Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a GUID as token:-

```
Function GetGUID()

    GetGUID = CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib").GUID 

End Function
```

Answer (score 4):

I know the question has already been marked as Answered, but I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6128940/when-its-necessary-to-protect-forms-with-token-csrf-attacks) helpful (doesn't really answer your question), particularly the second response which references [Chris Shiflett's article](http://shiflett.org/articles/cross-site-request-forgeries) explaining CSRF and a simple solution (answers your question plus some).

Here is how you might convert Chris's PHP to VBScript:

```
Dim token
token = md5(GetGUID())
Session("token")=token
Session("token_time")=Time() ' if you want to allow for a small window of time

' checks to make sure the request method is truly a post-back
If Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_METHOD") = "POST" Then
    ' Prevent CSRF (Cross-Site Request Forgeries) by comparing request-generated tokens. See http://shiflett.org/articles/cross-site-request-forgeries
    If Request.Form("token") = Session("token") Then
        ' Request is a post-back and is not a CSRF  
    End If
End If
```

You can have a look at the `md5()` function (used to hash the GUID) [here](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.Asp?ID=2366). The `md5` hash isn't necessary, but does add another layer of uniqueness and security.

Comment: thanks for your answer and especially the link to shiflett's article! i implemented the token thing just like you said and i think i will also use the md5 thing.

Comment: An md5 is a hash, which actually takes away uniqueness. I don't think it is enough to worry about, but if you are doing md5 to make a shorter string or make people think it isn't a GUID, then it's fine I'm sure, but md5 is considered obsolete now because it was broken (they can manufacture a collision).