# String comparison failure vbscript

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have code like this

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <%
        Function GetGUID()
            GetGUID = CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib").GUID
        End Function

        if Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_METHOD") = "POST" then
            if session("token") = cstr(Request.Form("csrftoken")) then
                response.write("Same")
            else
                response.write("different")
            end if

        else
            dim token
            token = GetGUID()
            session("token")=token
        end if
    %>
    <form method="post" action="test.asp">
        <input type="text" name="nama" placeholder="Input name">
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
        <input type="hidden" value="<%= session("token") %>" name="csrftoken">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I click the submit button, different always be printed. I'am very sure that those variable(session & csrftoken) have the same value, because I already check that via printing those variable.

## UPDATE

Thanks all for all your help, the problem is fixed now. It's because GUID that return null-terminated string.
For reference you can see here: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968756/how-to-generate-a-guid-in-vbscript/968767#968767). Thanks Lankymart for the reference :)

Comment: Perhaps a whitespace issue? Try putting both variables between `_` when printing them.

Comment: Okay, let me try that

Comment: There are no white space problem, but I dont know. Why after I print the session variable, I cant concatenate it with "_".

This is my code: http://pastebin.com/NDp1jSAP

Comment: If you can't concatenate it it's probably not a string in the first place. Try `CStr(session("token")) = CStr(Request.Form("csrftoken"))`.

Comment: already tried that.
The session object still can't concatenate with "_".
The request form is fine, I can concatenate it with "_".

Here is my new paste: http://pastebin.com/mrkgyzca

Comment: Then there is something not right with the `Session("token")` variable where is it set, can you check the `VarType()` maybe?

Comment: In the else section. So when my page is load, the session("token") will be initialized.
Both have 8 value of vartype

Comment: I think the problem is from CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib").GUID

Comment: I think that is a fair assessment, you sure `.GUID` returns a string and not an `Object`? Maybe this will help [How to generate a GUID in VBScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/968767/692942)

Comment: @Lankymart honestly I dont know what GUID returns, I used that only for generate some unique number.

I refer to this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421417/howto-implement-synchronizer-token-pattern-in-classic-asp

Comment: Ohhhhh I seee thanks @Lankymart for the reference

Answer (score 0):

Do not ask me WHY, but there are 2 chars at the end of your  `CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib").GUID` which are somehow lost when pushing it through as `post`. I will update this answer as soon as I find out more, but for now, you could just compare all the "real" chars, by making a `left` of the session variable by the length of the request variable. like this:

```
    if left(session("token"), len(Request.Form("csrftoken"))) = Request.Form("csrftoken")then
```

Also: you can use `trim` instead of `cstr`. It implies a `cstr` and trims the string.

Edit:
So the "Why" part got answered in the question linked by @Lankymart. Thanks!

Comment: For reference - [How to generate a GUID in VBScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/968767/692942) explains the NULL terminator and the weird behaviour it can cause.