# How can I prevent csrf attack in classic asp site?

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, csrf-protection

I have an application which is developed in vb6 and classic asp (12 years back). Now I have to prevent it from Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: This article - [Preventing CSRF and XSRF Attacks](https://blog.codinghorror.com/preventing-csrf-and-xsrf-attacks/) by our very own [Jeff Atwood♦](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) details two approaches you can take, depending on how far you want to go I'd go with the first approach.

Comment: Thanks @Lankymart for your comment. but here I'm looking for specific code to achieve this in classic asp. I'm well aware of CSRF and how to prevent it in latest application like MVC. But I don't know how to achieve it in classic asp site which was developed with vb6 code 12 years back..

Comment: Good that you understand in which case the implementation is no different just the tech stack is. So why you asking the question? You just want the codez?? That is not what [so] is about, you post how you have personally attempting this problem with a clear [mcve] and we will try to help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can achieve it pretty much the same way like in asp.net mvc.

1. generate a token on the Server and store it (e.g. in session)
2. send the token to the Client
3. the Client sends it back to the Server along with the "normal" form data
4. check the token on the Server if needed

you could even "copy" the asp.net functionality and write a vbscript function like this:

```
public function AntiForgeryToken()
    AntiForgeryToken = "<input type=""hidden"" name=""CSRFToken"" value=""" & session("CSRFToken") & """/>"
end function

' then in every form as needed:

<form>
<%=AntiForgeryToken()%>
<input type="text" name="" value="">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

further reading:

[synchronizer token pattern in classic asp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421417/howto-implement-synchronizer-token-pattern-in-classic-asp)

[Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: Great answer but your just feeding question like this that want the work done for them.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ulluoink